# Objective C Complition Block caused crash in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm new in Swift I have a code in Objective c and in this code, an NSMUtableDictionary is returned as a composition handler block.

I need to hit API and return API response dictionary in completion block.
My code is running perfectly in Objective c. But when I call same methd from swift using bridge header it causes crash.

My Objective C Code is:

**MYClass.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MYClass : NSObject
typedef void(^MyCompletionHandler)(NSMutableDictionary *_Nullable);

+ (void)myMethod:(NSString*_Nullable)param ComplitionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler _Nullable)complitionHandler;
@end
```

**MYClass.m**

```
#import "MYClass.h"
@implementation MYClass
 + (void)myMethod:(NSString*_Nullable)param ComplitionHandler:(MyCompletionHandler _Nullable)complitionHandler  {


dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
/// here I've written code to hit APi and got successfull response in nsmutableDict
NSMutableDictionary *response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

response = jSonResponse;


 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            complitionHandler (response);
        });

});
}
@end
```

Now When I use it in my App if I used in Objective C it is running perfectly but if I import this file in Swift Bridging header and when I used it in Swift file it causes a crash

**In Objective C:**

```
[MYClass myMethod:@”param Value” ComplitionHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary * MyResponse) {
        NSLog(@"Response = %@",MyResponse);           
   }];
```

**And In swift**

```
MYClass.myMethod("param Value", complitionHandler: {(MyResponse: NSMutableDictionary) -> Void in
            print("MyResponse = \(MyResponse)")
        } as? MyCompletionHandler)
```

In swift Crash Happens In the following line

```
complitionHandler (response);
```

When Response needs to be returned in completion block

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   complitionHandler (response);  //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
            });
```

Can anybody let me know what is the issue and how to resolve this. I need to use in in swift as well as in Objective c

Comment: check if your response parameter is nil, I think is a bad translation to swift, I think that parameter should be nullable in objective C and translated to swift should be `NSMutableDictionary?`

Comment: it is nullable already

Comment: please provide the whole code for swift you are using

Comment: @ReinierMelian is correct. In Swift your response is `NSMutableDictionary?`

Comment: Here are the response values:
If I put `NSLog(@"response = %@", response);` then I am getting following

`response =  {
    paramValue = sale;
    response =     {
        Authentication = fail;
        "Api_result" =         {
            Error = "Parameter missing,required value is empty or null";
            ErrorType = 7;
            saleResult = fail;
        };
    };
}`


I want to get same dictionary in swift also same as Objective c

Comment: Yes making NSMutableDictionary optional works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, Check if your response parameter is nil,Your issue is related to a bad swift translation, that parameter should be nullable in objective C and translated to swift should be `NSMutableDictionary?` and not `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Reinier Melian

`MYClass.myMethod("param Value", complitionHandler: {(MyResponse: NSMutableDictionary?) -> Void in
            print("MyResponse = \(MyResponse!)")
        })`


Workes for me

Comment: Your Answer Works for me and I've replied to you also

Answer (score 0):

First of all please enable debugging and add Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Exception Breakpoint.

Debugging in Xcode - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html

Find the error which is occurring

My version of code is this

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (NSMutableArray?) -> Void

  mycompletionBlock { (array) in
            print((array?.object(at: 0))!)

        }

    func mycompletionBlock(block: CompletionHandler)
    {
        let array = NSMutableArray()
        array.add("hello")

        block(array)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jest add **?** to `NSMutableDictionary`

```
MYClass.myMethod("param Value", complitionHandler: {(MyResponse: NSMutableDictionary?) -> Void in
            print("MyResponse = \(MyResponse)")
        } as? MyCompletionHandler)
```